# how to select json in kusto sql

Tags: azure-data-explorer, azure-sentinel

I want select json data in azure database using kusto sql.
see it the data.

[image]

the data in entities column. it looks like json type. but with [,]
i dont know why with [,].... not only {,}..

i want select like this in general sql type..
(select id, hostname, osfamily .... from SecurityAlert)

so, i tried like this...

```
SecurityAlert
| extend d=parse_json(Entities) 
| extend Entities=d.$id, id=d["$id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is in json array, so you need to "expand" the array using the [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator. Afterwards you can access it as you did using the dot "." notation.

Here is an example:

```
let SecurityAlerts = datatable(Entities:dynamic) [dynamic([{"$id":"4", "hostName":"a2"}, {"$id":"5", "hostName":"a3"}])];
SecurityAlerts 
| mv-expand Entities
| extend id = Entities.['$id'], hostName = Entities.hostName
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: i did..


`SecurityAlerts 
| mv-expand Entities
| extend id = Entities.['$id'], hostName = Entities.hostName`


but i got return from DB



'mvexpand' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'SecurityAlerts'
문제가 계속되는 경우 지원 티켓을 여세요. Request id: 12c100da-8156-4b93-9775-0caf2b62c337

Comment: looks like you are using the wrong table name, isn't it SecurityAlert and not SecurityAlerts?